# How identify a toastr in javascript to use later

Tags: jquery, toastr

I have some toastr (https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) triggered with timeout=0.

I have many datatables and before I load the data I show a toastr.
After the data loaded, I´d like to clear the toastr.

To do it, I´d like to put an ID to each toastr to use later in order to clear it.
For sample:

```
let t = toastr.info('Buscando...', 'Aguarde por favor', { timeOut: '0' });
t.attr('id', 'tid_tableChats');
```

later I´d like to do:

```
$("#tid_tableChats").clear();
```

But It doens´t work. Is there a solution todo it?

Comment: `clear()` isn't a jQuery method, it's a method of `toastr`. You should probably try `toastr.clear()`.

Comment: The link you provided provides a demo with that exact functionality.  https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html - in your case: `let t = toastr.info();` then `toastr.clear(t)`

Comment: As @BenM says you're mixing up toastr and jquery methods. You could also use $("#tid_tableChats").hide(); if you're going to use jquery to grab the toast

Comment: Ok, Thank you to all. I solved it